# After I upgraded my Flutter, this message appeared: Flutter: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have an issue after I upgraded my Flutter version to the latest version, on where it tells me that something wrong with my Gradle. I've checked all over Stack Overflow, and I also join the flutterdev on Discord, I tried one of the potential solutions like, reinstall my SDK tools, flutter clean, but none of them worked for me.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\PROJECT\flutter-project\dice_practice\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have downgraded my Flutter before, to the stable version of 3.3.0, but still with the same issue. Even I have tried almost all of the sdk-builds version. However, when I encountered this, I read somewhere on the community said that, probably I need to upgrade my Gradle.

As I upgraded it with Android Studio, it somehow worked, but the issue is, why do I need to upgrade for each project manually, isn't a way to upgrade globally? And is it my Gradle issue? Why this does happen so weirdly after I upgraded my Flutter? Do you guys also encounter the same issue?

Add: this also happens each time I create a new project.

Comment: I think you just needed to upgrade the kotlin version in your project. `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` would have done the job.

Comment: I've tried them but didn't work :(

Comment: Can you give more detail than "didn't work"? I am not sure there is much to go on here.

Comment: it does work now thankfully. it's apparently my gradle issue. that later on I have to delete the cache of gradle